# Why is Chrome Dev Tools console is instantly clearing all messages before i can even read them

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I realize i accidentally pressed some keyboard shortcuts while my focus was in dev tools, not in my code editor, and I've done something to me console where it is continually displaying on the top line, `Console was cleared` `code?id=105&subid=51763_4926_:1`, and on the second line, continually flashing `<img>` `code?id=105&subid=51763_4926_:1`.

If i `console.log` anything, it flashed for a second and is gone. What did i do and how do i get it back? I did reproduce for different pages, and reset the dev tools preferences to default.

Comment: Sounds like something is invoking console.clear(). You can reset devtools in its settings.

Comment: I did, in settings, "reset defaults and reload" but that did not help.

Comment: i unchecked preserve log and see that console.clear() is getting called..looking for where or how?

Comment: @bluedimensional in the console you should see the text "Console was cleared" - if you look to the far left of this line you should see some link text that looks something like "VM77:34" or "someJavascripFile.js:122".  Click this and the dev tools will open up the file where it was called from.

Comment: thank all of you you were all correct. turns out i had a browser hijacker! which i got removed by resetting the main chrome settings. What is best practice for me in this question, as far as marking, correctness, etc? I am still pretty new here.